# PLC Programming with C# in Rockwell-automation using RSLINX(OPC server) - how should I connect it to the OPC server?

Tags: c#, plc, opc

I am new to PLC Programming and I do not know the basic of it.

My task is to write a code in C# that sends and receive tags from/to their communication server OPC server) RSLINX which will be connected to the client's PLC. I have found the OPC CLient code in the C# but I can't find how should I connect it to the OPC server and is there any testing simulation available that could give me the testing data that I would be receiving from client's PLC. I can give you a reference of what the client is demanding. This is what the client said in the email.

**We currently do not have a copy of RSLinx installed in our system onsite.  The communications between our PLC and HMI is inherently built into the devices and configured using RSLinx Enterprise which is installed on our programming laptop.  We also use RSLinx on our laptop when we want to access the PLC or HMI using the respective programming software.
For your system to reach into our PLC data table, the RSLinx Gateway software will need to be installed and configured on your computer which is running your software and that needs to access our PLC.

I hope this makes sense.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to communicate with any Rockwell PLC, it's mandatory to have at least the RSLinx Classic. The RS Linx Enterprise or the FactoryTalk Linx Enterprise (the version depends on which FTV you are using), is to communicate the HMI Client to the PLC.
To enable the OPC communication you must have at least the RSLinx Classic installed, it has a built in OPC DA server. What the RSLinx Classic does is in rough words connect to the PLC over Ethernet/IP (or other communication protocol) and bridge the data as OPC server, which can be reached from OPC Clients.

To setup the communication you must configure a DDE/OPC Topic and point it to the PLC controller. This topic has a name, and this will be important to communicate.
I’ve done this long time ago, but as far as I remember, you setup a OPC client on C#. Important: there is a defined structure to fetch the data. Rockwell on the Knowledge Base has examples of it for VBA and Excel, and probably for .Net.

Long story short, to achieve the communication to the PLC and get data to your C# application, you must install the RSLinx Classis on your system, Setup a DDE/OPC Topic, your C# application must start a client connection to the OPC Server from RSLinx, then you set the methods to read or write the tag data.

If you have a TechConnect valid user, you can search for the ID QA769 to reach the forum topic: [RSLinx Classic: Monitor Data in Excel using DDE](https://rockwellautomation.custhelp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/42787/loc/en_US). This is not for C#, however, you can have a better picture to make the same in C#.

Somethings must be pointed out:

1. If you only want to read and write tags for education purposes, this is a nice way to comprehend how to program a OPC client.
2. If this application is a solution to the customer, probably you do not need to reinvent the wheel. There are several connection gateways on the market, such as Kepware and OAS which does the communication to the data you need and send to the destination you need (e.g. SQL database).
3. Depending of which data and how time-critical it is do not use OPC DA or DDE topics. The delay to write and read are ridiculous. You must forward to use OPC UA protocol or any CIP Net communication driver to the Rockwell PLC. OAS and Kepware has CIP net drivers to connect with Rockwell PLCs.
4. If you want to go for the OPC UA, you must you the FactoryTalk Linx.
5. There are some tutorials to create a OPC UA client in C# such this one [OPC-UA - C# .Net](http://opcfoundation.github.io/UA-.NETStandard/), even in NodeJS such as this one [OPC-UA – NodeJS](https://node-opcua.github.io/)

I hope I could help you. If you need more information or have more questions let me know.
Good Luck.

Comment: Wow you pretty much explained very well. I will do it as you said an keep on posting and updating you. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi, is there any difference between factorytalk linx and rslinx classic.

Comment: That's a good question. I'm aware that Rockwell have realease the FactoryTalk Linx (former FactoryTalk Gateway).

My opinion that the FTLinx will be the new version of the RSLinx... I'm not quite sure, because I haven't participate on their events to see how they are moving forward.

What I can affirm you is:
To use OPC DA and DDE Topics for older firmware versions, go to RSLogix.
To newer firmware versions and OPC-UA go for the FactoryTalk Linx.

I don't know if they will depricate the RSLinx and substitute with FTLinx, but this would be my guess.

Comment: Ok so I have used OPC UA for my C# client application to connect to the OPC server RSLINX Classic

Comment: Becareful, to use OPC UA as your communication protocol you must use the FactoryTalk Linx and NOT the RSLinx Classic. 

In theory you can use the OPC-UA for OPC DA, but you'll need to make a com wrapper to make it work.

I adivise you to make things as simple as possible: Use the FactoryTalk Linx and use the OPC Foundation .Net Library.

Comment: If you have the TechConnect, search for the ID IN7861 [FactoryTalk Linx OPC-UA Server](https://rockwellautomation.custhelp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1072183). Or use this literature from Rockwell [FactoryTalk Linx Gateway Getting Results Guide](https://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/gr/ftlg-gr001_-en-e.pdf)

Comment: I have to use OPC UA, is there any workaround if I can connect to (RSLINX) OPC server.

Comment: FactoryTalk Linx creates the OPC UA server as you need. It connects to the PLC and broadcast the tags as OPC-UA Server. On your .Net (C#) application you create a client, and subscribe to the EndPointURL from the OPC-UA which you create on FTLinx to reach the tags you want.

Comment: Are you aware that OPC DA and OPC-UA are different protocols right? OPC is very old, it's on the maket for almost 20 years already. The OPC-UA is the evolution of it, designed as an open architecture...

Comment: OPC UA has free .net libraries. DO you know what should I need to create a client application in C# using OPC DA as I would be using Rslin classic gateway.

Comment: Sorry, but I've never used OPC DA in .NET (C#). However, I was taking a look on the documentation of this OPC UA .Net library from OPC Foundation, and seems like that they have an example to use it to access data from OPC DA. Here is the link:

[Documentaion](http://opcfoundation.github.io/UA-.NETStandard/help/index.htm#overview.htm)

Take a look on the documentation, and try to make the client example as they explain there. Perhaps it'll be useful for what you need.

Comment: As far as I remember It's not free, it has license GPL 2.0, you must disclose the code.

Comment: Hi do you know how I can purchase a licensed rslinx gateway. I mean what is the procedure to have the techconnect account

Comment: Hi, you must get in contact with Rockwell Automation Distributor. It depends where you are located. In most of the countries you must get in contact with a distributor, from the website www.ab.com you mayfind the contacts. Therefore, you must inquiry to the sales agent the information to purchase the FactoryTalk Linx license, or a TechConnect subscription...

Comment: _to communicate with any Rockwell PLC, it's mandatory to have at least the RSLinx Classic_ actually no, it's not.  There are third party OPC servers available, eg Matrikon and Kepware to name two

Answer (score 0):

You can download libplctag C class libraries from GitHub here that assist in connection and communication for reading/writing tag values within an AB PLC: https://github.com/libplctag/libplctag from there, you can watch a few youtube examples.
Mesta-Automation has a decent article on how to compile the libraries with an included video you can check out here https://www.mesta-automation.com/how-to-communicate-to-an-allen-bradley-plc-with-c-and-libplctag-ethernet-ip-library/
You don't need RSLinx to communicate with the controller with this method.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but client demanded that the RSLinx Gateway software will need to be installed and configured on my computer which is running my software and that needs to access client's PLC.

Comment: If you're trying to connect directly to the opc server You can check out the OPC DA.Net wrapper from Advosol.  They have an evaluation version, however it's not free but should be what you need. http://advosol.com/product/1/opcda-net

Comment: If it worked, please mark as correct answer.  Thanks! :)

Comment: unfortunately, their evaluation version has some fatal error and couldn't install